# Linux Mint does not start after renaming home directory

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I  am new to linux and was just trying to rename the only directory in home from `rk` to rhk.

I messed up the whole thing and the settings. Created some new thing named rhk which I can't remember as it got all messed up and  Now I am getting nothing after Linux Mint 10(julia) boots up - no start menu, no panel, no taskbar nothing.

I tried to work in the recovery mode and got some(downloaded) 216mb of something(in the repair broken packages) hoping that it might help but didn't help.

Moreover whenver I  have booted in it shows messages like

```
Could not update ICEauthority file /home/rk./.ICEauthority                                                                                                                  
 there is a problem with the configuration server. (usr/lib/libconfig24/gconfsanitycheck2 exited with status 256)                                                                                                                                         
 The panel encountered a problem while loading "OAFIID: GNOME_mintMenu"                                                                                                               
 The panel encountered a problem while loading "OAFIID: GNOME_IndicatorApplet" 
 Naulitis could not create the following reqiured folders: /home/rk/Desktop, /home/rk/. Naulitis
```

Moreover <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> gives Run application or run with file and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: There also seems to be something wrong with your keyboard.

Comment: What the[?](http://superuser.com/q/259826/4377)

Comment: Congrats on managing to edit this, @Sathya!

Answer (score 2):

Boot into "recovery mode", choose the `root` option to get a console, and type the following and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
usermod -d /home/rhk rk
```

That will tell the operating system that you moved `rk`'s home directory to `/home/rhk`.  You need to do this when you move your home directory, otherwise it will try to load your desktop settings from `/home/rk` and it won't find them, resulting in the behavior you described.

Answer (score 1):

You changed your users Home directory which contains files used by the GUI "Nautilus" to show your panels etc you need to rename it back from "rhk" to "rk" or update your users information.

1. Try getting to a prompt by hitting Ctrl+Alt+(F1-F6).
2. Login at the prompt and rename your directory back using "sudo mv -r /home/rhk /home/rk" or update your information using "sudo usermod -d /home/rhk rk"
3. Switch back using Ctrl+Alt+F7 and then hit Ctrl+Alt+Backspace if this does not reload your GUI try rebooting.

If you cannot get to a command prompt at step one try rebooting in safe mode and issuing the commands.